# Как сохранить ключ в ChoiceBox

Tags: javafx

уважаемые гуру!
В HTML есть прекрасный тег `<select>` где внутренний тег `<option>` принимает `value` который может действует как отдельный параметр. `<option value="1">Шапокляк</option>` В итоге я могу отобразить текст "Шапокляк", и указать в `value` `ID=1` этой записи. 
Так вот. Пишу на **JavaFX** приложение и задался следующим вопросом:
Из всех выпадающих списков, я нашел только **ChoiceBox** и **ComboBox**. Вся проблема в том, что они принимают только `observableArrayList` а это значит, что в любом случае я могу установить только значения, который попадают в список, и их индексы идут по очереди:

```
>   ObservableList<String> langs = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Java", "Java", "JavaScript", "C#");
>   ComboBox<String> langsComboBox = new ComboBox<String>(langs);
```

Но т.к. список может содержать много одинаковых значений, я не могу ориентироваться на поле **"значения"**.
Мне нужен именно `id` этого значения. 
Пока в голову приходит только нечто подобное:
Из выборки БД создать `HashMap<K,<K,V>>`, где начальный K - это номер по порядку.
Далее `HashMap<K,<K,V>>` преобразовывать в `ArrayList` (начальный `K` как `index` в `ArrayList`, `V` - устанавливать именно значением `ChoiceBox`).
Далее вешать слушатель `langsComboBox.setOnAction`, и по клику получать `index` этой записи.
Далее: пробегаться по `HashMap<K,<K,V>>` и по за `index` искать второй `K`, что и будет являться значением?
Но мне кажется данный вариант слишком уж преувеличенным.
**Есть ли более простые методы как это сделать?**  
Или кто-нибудь, может быть, поделится собственными примерами реализации выпадающих списков? (достаточно просто примера)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам спросил, сам отвечу)) Довольно-таки простой способ, кстати.

Сам класс `Organization`

```
public class Organization {
    public int idOrganization;
    public String nameOrganization;

    public Organization() {
    }

    public Organization(int idOrganization, String nameOrganization) {
        this.idOrganization = idOrganization;
        this.nameOrganization = nameOrganization;
    }

    public int getIdOrganization() {
        return idOrganization;
    }

    public String getNameOrganization() {
        return nameOrganization;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getNameOrganization();
    }
    }
```

Далее исполнение уже где угодно:

```
    public ChoiceBox<Organization> organization;//установка нашего списка в контроллере
    List<Organization> list = new ArrayList<>(); //создаем пустой список
    ObservableList<Organization> binOrganization = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
            organization.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Organization>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Organization> observable, Organization oldValue, Organization newValue) {
                    System.out.println(newValue.getIdOrganization());
                    System.out.println(newValue.getNameOrganization());
                }
            });
    //присваиваем значения
    binOrganization.add(new Organization(41, "Организация 1"));
    binOrganization.add(new Organization(25, "Новая ООО"));
    binOrganization.add(new Organization(8, "МУП Какой-то"));
    //и устанавливаем в наш ChoineBox
    organization.setItems(binOrganization);
```

В итоге, вместо `System.out.println` можно уже присвоить какую-то другую переменную, которая будет использоваться в следующей `Scene`.
Всем спасибо **:)**